Reducing the gap in the Lemma environment with enumerate
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.

    \item $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$.

    \item $(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3.$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}

Once you compile this, you will see that there is a gap (please see the screenshot). I am wondering how to reduce that gap.


There are several earlier questions that address this.  See the subsection "Lists in theorem environments" under this "Often referenced question".

If you are willing to start the enumerated list on a new line, just insert \leavevmode before \begin{enumerate}; otherwise, this question provides an answer: Annoying space before the first item in an enumeration which starts a theorem.

It's easiest to just set the first element manually, then start an enumerate from 2 (using the optional argument supplied by enumitem.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
  1. $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.

  \begin{enumerate}[start = 2]
    \item $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$.

    \item $(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3.$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}

\labelsep is the typical separation between the label and the content, so you could also use
   1.\hspace{\labelsep}$...$


For \items that span multiple lines, using a manually-inserted 1. for the first item results in a non-aligned indentation in subsequent lines. Placing \showthe\leftmargin inside the enumerate environment will give you an indication of the typical indentation, which you can then use to set the \hangindent (25pt in the example below):

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
  \hangindent=25pt\relax
  1. $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. \lipsum[1][1-2]

  \begin{enumerate}[start = 2]
    \item $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$. \lipsum[1][3-4]
    %\showthe\leftmargin % To find the left margin of the enumerate (check the console)
    \item $(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3.$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}


Thank you! However, it does not look nice if the content of item 1 exceeds one line. I hope you understand what I mean. Just add a few more lines in the first item, and you will see that the starting points of the items are different.

@RFZ: See the updated answer.

I'd set the indentation to zero for all items, by loading the enumitem package and starting the enumerate environment with the option left=0pt. Optionally, I'd force the numerals to use upright digits in order to hightlight their "structural" nature or role. This may be achieved by specifying the option label=\upshape\arabic*..

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
  \begin{enumerate}[left=0pt, label=\upshape\arabic*.]
    \item $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.
    \item $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$.
    \item $(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3.$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}


Thank you! But this is slightly different from what I have. In your case, all items start immediately on the next line, but if you notice, in my case, there is a short gap when each item starts.
